# How to calculate page loading time in Ionic 3 (single page app)?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, single-page-application

I am creating a function that calculates a page loading time for each page of my Ionic 3 App (I use lazy loading). However, I am currently stuck in issues:

- When does the page start creating HTML?
- When does the page finish creating HTML?
- When does the page complete downloading all resources on the page (image, etc …)?

Can anyone give me advice?

Comment: imho if you want to measure actual user experience ideally you should want to measure rendering of pages etc from external perspective and not via internal lifecycle hooks.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to look at is https://blog.ionicframework.com/navigating-lifecycle-events/ this contains the ionic life-cycle eg.  `ionViewDidLoad()`: Fired only when a view is stored in memory. This event is NOT fired on entering a view that is already cached. It’s a nice place for init related tasks.

Ionic 3's pages are also angular components so I'd imagine the another thing to look at is the component hooks. These methods are fired when in the stages of the component life cycle.

https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks 
https://www.intertech.com/Blog/angular-component-lifecycle/

eg. `ngAfterViewInit(){ stopTimer() } //this method is fired once Angular initializes component and child component content`

To achive what you want you could have a provider that both pages link to. When you change page start a timer and stop it using `ngAfterViewInit()` or other more appropriate hook.